Can Anyone Make Out All the Characters on the Lid of This Antique Chinese Snuff Box?

There appear to be five different sets of characters on the lid of this antique Chinese snuff box. I can make out clearly only the first, on the very right, 大吉利 (roughly, "good fortune"), and the last, in the lower left corner, 半瓦 (seemingly a kind of measurement, referring to either the height of the box or the volume of snuff that it could contain). Can anyone make out the other three sets of characters, some of which seem quite stylized, in between?

白（伯）Ｘ乍（作）寳【⿰阝】（尊）彝 // 宜子孫吉 // 延秊（年）. I can't recognise Ｘ but 伯Ｘ is likely a name/title. Once you're confident in your own interpretation, please write up an answer!
